# values function in ydn-db not working in safari and iOS9

Tags: javascript, web, safari, ios9, ydn-db

The get,values,count function of ydn db is not working in safari and ios9.

I have tried to reopen the db and then access it but still no luck.

```
  db_mob_audit = new ydn.db.Storage('idb_mob_auditor', schema);
  db_mob_audit.values('DomainInfo',key_range,9999).done(function (tempDdata) {
            if (tempDdata.length > 0) {}
  });
```

After doing this i get error
"can't find variable window-ydn db".

Answer (score 0):

I think because of schema or some platform problem. Please check error during opening the database (always better to check error). [Use dev version](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/doc/usage/debugging.html) to get more information about the problem.

```
db_mob_audit = new ydn.db.Storage('idb_mob_auditor', schema);
db_mob_audit.onReady(function(e) {
  if (e) {
     window.console.error(e);
     // do plan B here
  }
  // begin using db from here
}
```

Also check out limitation on Safari by running unit tests on different storage mechanisms. Safari does look good.

http://dev.yathit.com/test/test_all.html?websql

http://dev.yathit.com/test/test_all.html?indexeddb

If still have problem, create a minimal unit test and file an issue at [github](https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db/issues/new).